# VerifyHash seems to work on Windows, but fails on Linux

Tags: c#, .net-core, rsa

I'm creating a .net core application and I want it to work on both Windows and Linux.
In my app I'm using VerifyHash to verify file hashes, everything works great on Windows but it fails on linux.

```
public static bool ValidateSignature(byte[] sha256, string signature)
{
    if (_rsaCryptoServiceProvider == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(signature))
    {
        return false;
    }

    var test = _rsaCryptoServiceProvider.VerifyHash(sha256, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"), Base64.Decode(signature));
    Console.WriteLine("SHA256: " + Sha256ToString(sha256));
    Console.WriteLine("SIGNATURE: " + signature);
    Console.WriteLine("Match: " + test);

    return test;
}
```

I added these debug WriteLines to check if function get the same data, and it does.

This is my output from Windows:

```
SHA256: 4146024cf95ed34573d2dabde7569f1ca3611091760060c9fee718522890519e
SIGNATURE: H+FOxGDT3vE8fA6oyKIH56fVCipRkf6oidxU0KnvCvADGu083h196dPv4lWwi5i0XATygABqEbS0iwLBXFtrhoX5wxLRkpnpnZjTEgcONWrKe78wYKKwAqUfVWyT6VuQGX3bpcSHlvTUsbtZAins2BBp7kS2CtivVwU1G87+cNs=
Match: True
```

And this is output from Linux:

```
SHA256: 4146024cf95ed34573d2dabde7569f1ca3611091760060c9fee718522890519e
SIGNATURE: H+FOxGDT3vE8fA6oyKIH56fVCipRkf6oidxU0KnvCvADGu083h196dPv4lWwi5i0XATygABqEbS0iwLBXFtrhoX5wxLRkpnpnZjTEgcONWrKe78wYKKwAqUfVWyT6VuQGX3bpcSHlvTUsbtZAins2BBp7kS2CtivVwU1G87+cNs=
Match: False
```

Hash and signature are exactly the same but linux fails to verify it.

I checked if the signature match on the linux machine using openssl, here's my output:

```
$ cat mod.dll | openssl dgst -sha256
(stdin)= 4146024cf95ed34573d2dabde7569f1ca3611091760060c9fee718522890519e

$ cat mod.dll | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl rsautl -inkey key -sign | base64
H+FOxGDT3vE8fA6oyKIH56fVCipRkf6oidxU0KnvCvADGu083h196dPv4lWwi5i0XATygABqEbS0
iwLBXFtrhoX5wxLRkpnpnZjTEgcONWrKe78wYKKwAqUfVWyT6VuQGX3bpcSHlvTUsbtZAins2BBp
7kS2CtivVwU1G87+cNs=
```

As you can see signature and hash from openssl matches so the signature is 100% okay, there's something wrong in the VerifyHash function.

There's my code for creating and disposing service provider:

```
private static void _UpdateCrypto()
{
    var key = PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(_key);
    var rsaKey = (RsaKeyParameters) key;

    var parameters = new RSAParameters
    {
        Modulus = rsaKey.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
        Exponent = rsaKey.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned()
    };

    _rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    _rsaCryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters(parameters);
}

public static void Dispose()
{
    _rsaCryptoServiceProvider?.Dispose();
}
```

_key is byte[] field, it's a .der file loaded into a byte array, _UpdateCrypto() is called at the start of the program.

Comment: Check if reverting decoded Base64 string in Linux will do the trick. I think this problem related to byte order on different machines.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a byte order problem, reverting decoded base64 didn't help.

Comment: Can you provide code which responsible for instantiation and disposing of provider class?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: Does `VerifyHash(hash, signature, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1)` work?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I just used BouncyCastle library instead and it works great.

That's my code for verifying signatures if someone needs:

```
public static bool ValidateSignature(byte[] sha256, string signature)
{
    if (_asymmetricBlockCipher == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(signature))
    {
        return false;
    }

    var decoded = Base64.Decode(signature);
    return _asymmetricBlockCipher.ProcessBlock(decoded, 0, decoded.Length).SequenceEqual(sha256);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. I'm presuming you are using Mono on Linux, you may want to file a bug report. Mono seems to be a clean room implementation of .NET classes, so it might be that this indicates a bug. You might want to include the version of Mono on your machine in the question just in case.

Comment: I'm not using Mono, I'm using .NET Core 2.1.4

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that the text file (JSON) file I used as input to:

```
new HMACSHA256(key).ComputeHash(text)
```

had `CRLF` line ending, so it worked in Visual Studio on Windows, but failed on the Ubuntu agent.

Changing the line endings for the text file to `LF` fixed it.